# Can I take unopened sealed tea bags to Mexico from the U.K.?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, mexico

All official links I can find are in Spanish.

I’d like to take some tea bags to Mexico, is this allowed and do I have to declare them?

Comment: Could you give some indication to the amount of some?

Comment: @Notts90 This is a list of permitted products https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/boston/images/pdfs/products.pdf Tea isn’t specifically mentioned

Comment: @CGCampbell a medium size pack from the supermarket, enough to last two weeks for a heavy tea drinker 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Anecdotal self-answer**
We decided to bring the tea bags with us. Coincidentally we were selected for a bag search while going through customs and the customs officer wasn’t the least bit interested in the tea bags and let us through after little more than a cursory search.

As such it would seems it’s perfect acceptable and we’re glad we brought them as the tea here is Lipton.

Comment: That sounds like a good enough answer, esp as you were checked. When you can, go ahead and accept yourself (it's definitely allowed.)

Answer (score 3):

I took tea with me to mexico in 2010 and in 2015. My bag was selected and searched. The Officer found tea bags and asked whether this was tea (I use Twinings large square tea bags with not tag and I did not have original packaging). It was fine.